# Operating with Python class and objects

Tags: python, class, object, vector

I want to create both a Vector class and a Point class and have a function inside the Vector class that is able to add a Vector object and a Point object, but I don't understand how I have to operate with the internal variables of the classes. This is the code I have right now:

```
class Vector:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def AddVector(self, point):
        point2 = Point(0, 0)
        point.x + self.x = point2.x
        point.y + self.y = point2.y
        return point2

class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

p1 = Point(2,3)
v1 = Vector(4,7)


def main():
    Vector.AddVector(p1,v1)
    print(point2.x, point2.y)

main()
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: First, are you sure you want to mutate the point, instead of returning a new point? Second, are you sure you want the API to be `vector.AddVector(point)` instead of `point.AddVector(vector)`, or just `point + vector`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, don't use global variables. It is a bad habit. Move them into main.

Then, the main problem, call method on the instances (`p1` and `v1`) and not on classes (`Vector` and `Point`). Third, use the returned variable. Therefore:

```
def main():
    p1 = Point(2,3)
    v1 = Vector(4,7)
    p2 = p1.AddVector(v1)
    print(p2.x, p2.y)
```

The next problem is, this is invalid syntax:

```
point.x + self.x = point2.x
```

The correct way to assign is the other way around:

```
point2.x = point.x + self.x
```

Then, you have `AddVector` method on `Vector`. It should be on a `Point` and it should receive a `Vector` as argument.

All together:

```
class Vector:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def AddVector(self, v):
        point2 = Point(0, 0)
        point2.x = self.x + v.x
        point2.y = self.y + v.y
        return point2

def main():
    p1 = Point(2,3)
    v1 = Vector(4,7)
    p2 = p1.AddVector(v1)
    print(p2.x, p2.y)

main()
```

Of course, it could be nicer, this is more advanced, but here it is for completeness:

```
class Vector:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Vector({}, {})'.format(self.x, self.y)


class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __add__(self, v):
        return Point(self.x + v.x, self.y + v.y)

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Point({}, {})'.format(self.x, self.y)

def main():
    p1 = Point(2,3)
    v1 = Vector(4,7)
    p2 = p1 + v1
    print(p2)

main()
```

Comment: An even nicer way to do this would be with `namedtuple` or `dataclass`, so you don't have to define those `__init__` and `__repr__` methods. Also, maybe a check to prevent you from meaninglessly adding two points (the same way `datetime + timedelta` and `timedelta + timedelta` are legal but `datetime + datetime` is not). But I think you've explained enough here that you don't need to go into even more detail…

Comment: @abarnert Thanks for the reference to `dataclass`, I did not know about that one :) As for other remarks, I agree, but it would be too much here.

Comment: Well, you still have to wait to the far-off future date of 27 June 2018 before you can use `dataclass` without installing something off PyPI… Anyway, as I said, I think you've explained enough, and I don't want to push you to make your answers even more overly verbose than mine usually are. :)